# slideToggle div on click conflicting with the div's inner button

Tags: jquery, html

so here is what i have(minimal code):

```
<head>
<style>
    .container {
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        width: 300px;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="additional">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <button>action 1</button>
            <button>action 2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--  jquery  -->
    <script
        src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        var additional = $(".additional");
        var container = $(".container");
        // by default
        additional.slideToggle(0);
        // on click
        container.on('click', function(){
            additional.slideToggle(0);  
        });
</script>
```

so my issue is rather simple, at least I hope it is... all that i am trying to achieve is: when either "action 1" or "action 2" buttons are clicked, I want the `additional` div to stay open. currently it closes according to the `container.on('click', ...` event. any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Normal thing, You can't hide the container without hiding the additional because it's his child node, you have to separate them

Comment: @Daouda no you don't. See my answer for how.

Comment: You are correct, I upvote your answer. I am not that much expert, but I think my logic is also right it's about propagation, and you show just show that we can stop event propagation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can identify by simple javascript event `event.target.tagName`...

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
<style>
    .container {
        background-color: #eeeeee;
        width: 300px;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Header</h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="additional">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
            <button>action 1</button>
            <button>action 2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <!--  jquery  -->
    <script
        src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
        var additional = $(".additional");
        var container = $(".container");
        // by default
        additional.slideToggle(0);
        // on click
        container.on('click', function(event){
        if(event.target.tagName !== "BUTTON"){
            additional.slideToggle(0);  
        }
        });
</script>
```

Comment: This is actually both standard and brilliant, Totally missed on that. Thank you @parth

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because the click event on the button is propagating up the DOM to the `.container`, whose click event is then triggered which hides the `.additional`.

To fix this you can either check the target of the click in the `.container` click handler:

```js
var $additional = $(".additional");
var $container = $(".container");

$additional.slideToggle(0);

$container.on('click', function(e) {
  if (!$(e.target).is('button'))
    $additional.slideToggle(0);
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="additional">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <button>action 1</button>
    <button>action 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or alternatively you can attach a click handler to the buttons which prevents the event bubbling up the DOM:

```js
var $additional = $(".additional");
var $container = $(".container");

$additional.slideToggle(0);

$container.on('click', function() {
  $additional.slideToggle(0);
});

$container.find('button').click(function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```css
.container {
  background-color: #eeeeee;
  width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h1>Header</h1>
  <hr>
  <div class="additional">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    <button>action 1</button>
    <button>action 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you Roy, Please, I wanna make sure of two things: one - my `$container` and its `$additional` div are generated using AJAX so will `.find()` bind to them? two - once `action 1` is click a modal will fire up, is `stopPropagation` going to prevent that?

Comment: 1) yes, so long as you execute `find()` *after* they have been added to the DOM 2) Only if it's a delegated event handler, otherwise it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you Rory your answer speaks a lot about your skills and experience, I am going to go with @parth solution since it is a safer bet. BTW love your website :)